# Match one field and ignore others

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my data like this:

```
  {"_id":"5c0a17013d8ca91bf4ee7885",
    "ep1":{
        "email":"test@gmail.com",
        "password":"123456",
        "phoneNo":"123456789",
        "endpointId":"ep1"
        }
  }
```

I want to match all the object that has key **ep1** and value **"email":"test@gmail.com"** and set **ep1:{}**

**Code:**

> My req object is like this {"endpointId":"ep1", "email":
>   "test@gmail.com"}

```
    let query = {[req.body.endpointId]:{email: req.body.email}};
        endpointModelData.endpoint.updateMany(query, {[req.body.endpointId]:{}}, {multi: true}, function(err, doc){
            if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
            console.log(doc)
            return res.status(201).send("success.");
        })
```

But this code only works if there is only **one entry(that is email)** inside my **ep1** object

like this:

```
{"_id":"5c0a17013d8ca91bf4ee7885",
    "ep1":{
        "email":"test@gmail.com"
        }
  }
```

So, how can I match email and ignore other fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match: `{"ep1.email":"test@gmail.com"}` so change your `query` to:

```
let query = { [`${req.body.endpointId}.email`]: req.body.email };
```

You can see that [filter working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HQ_Mag2wY-K)

On the end of the day your update should look like:

```
updateMany({ "ep1.email" : "test@gmail.com" }, { "ep1": {} }, {multi: true})
```

Comment: That helps me. Thank you.